# problems with read.table in R

Tags: r, read.table

Here I have a .csv dataset containing 120211 observations for 19 variables.
Using `read.table("test.csv",header=TRUE,sep=",")` will yield the following error:

```
scan(file, what, nmax, sep, dec, quote, skip, nlines, na.strings, : line 19 has no 19 variables
```

Then I add the `fill=TRUE` in read.table arguments and no error will be shown.
However using this will only yield 41451 observations. And the 41451st observation is actually the last one in my test.csv.

Can anyone help me ?
Thanks.

Comment: If you have a .csv file why don't you use `read.csv`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without the dataset it is hard to check what the problem is. 
I suppose in line 41453 there is in one cell (string/text) an additional comma. 
Are the text/string variables quoted?
Just try to check the line 41453 (because you have to count the header line, too) with a text editor like notepad++ to identify your problem.

Comment: could you tell me your email?So I can send you the dataset. It's originally an .xlsx and I  save as .csv. please. I am a fresh for R.

Comment: thanks. i fix the problem when I tried using the original syntax
read.table("test.csv",header=TRUE,sep=",")